# Internet explorer is taking text of inner tag as continuation of outer text by using element.getext() ,while it is working fine on chrome and firefox

Tags: selenium, xpath

I only need the text of the outer tag and not the text of inner tag, when i am extracting the text using element.gettext() in chrome and firefox it is giving me output as 157 0 while on IE output is 1570.

Please refer to attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy68g.png)

Comment: Can you show the definition of `element`?

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 solutions as follows :

- Instead of `element.gettext();` use :

  ```
  element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- Use the `xpath` as :

  ```
  "//span[@class='ng-binding' and not(@class='ng-scope')]"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get text from both "child" and "parent" elements and then remove one from another

```
WebElement parent = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding']"));
WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.xpath(".//sup"));
String parentText = parent.getText();
String childText = child.getText();
String result = parentText.substring(0, parentText.lastIndexOf(childText));
```